Vuforia Model Target Generator not saving model targets
I am facing issues with the Model Target Generator application? Out of the few model targets I have made, only one has survived so far (see the image attached). I followed the app's instructions in setting up the other tagets and even generated guide views, which went well, but once I closed the app, the models would disappear, but my model counter was still decreasing. The model target folders on my machine were also empty after generating the other models.
How could I either recover the other models generated, or reset the counter back to 19 remaining model targets?
I tried contacting PTC, but they mentioned they only deal with licensing.

I'm not seeing any image. But I suggest to check the MTG_archived.log and see if there's some pointers to what happened. You can find the log in the menu from your user account icon. Also, make sure to not use a virtual drive, and if you are using a Mac, STEP (.stp) are not supported.

After noticing a number of Vuforia folders on my PC, I realized that the Model Target generator does not save the model targets generated in the same place each time. After searching for the folders called "Vuforia" in each of my drives, I came accross the multiple save locations of each model target generated.
